# Which tense should be in the following context?

Tags: grammar

Situation:

The electricity was cut off at 9 am. Now it's 11 am. It will be supplied at 12 o'clock.

How to describe the situation?

1. The electricity was cut off until 12 o'clock.
2. The electricity will be cut off until 12 o'clock.

Comment: Sentence 1) could be about yesterday's power cut. Sentence 2) could be better as "The electricity will be off until 12 o'clock." It was cut off at 9 and will be off until 12.

Comment: The electricity supply will be restored at 12 o'clock.